Missing "main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/" in Noble version of Ubuntu repository
I have an issue with my PXE script. For my old script, I used this path:
https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/
Now I want to switch to the Noble version for my new PXE script. Unfortunately, I can't find main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/ in this path:
https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/main/
This is crucial for my script. Any help would be appreciated!
